# Where to store API URL in Cypress?

Tags: javascript, cypress

I'm new to Cypress and want to know where's the place I should put all of my external URLs in?

In my website, we have separated URLs for the web, and another one for APIs.

Let's say they're:

- App URL: https://app.com
- API URL: https://api.myapi.com

I know I can put my app URL in `baseUrl` in `cypress.json`, and I've put all my subdirectory e.g. `/products` `/users` in the env variables session. Because `cy.visit()` automatically utilize this `baseUrl`, it's good for me now.

What I struck now is where to place my API URLs properly. I don't feel like put the fullpath like:

- https://api.myapi.com/products
- https://api.myapi.com/users
- https://api.myapi.com/users/1/edit

is not a good idea, since I repeated the API baseUrl everywhere. And if I split it into `apiBaseUrl` and the sub part `/products`, I'm now have to build up the URL myself every time I want to watch it like

```
cy.route(`${Cypress.env('apiBaseUrl')}${Cypress.env('apiUrl').getProducts}`);
```

because my `apiBaseUrl` is not `baseUrl`. This make it even harder than the above method.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

I found a quite simple solution.  Just simply put your API backend URL right next to the (web frontend) cypress 'baseUrl'.  My cypress.json looks like this:

```
{
  "baseUrl": "http://localhost:3001/",
  "backendBaseURL": "http://localhost:8080/api/v2",
  "env": {
    "someDummyEnvironemntVar": "fooBar"
  }, 
  "testFiles": "**/*.*",
  "watchForFileChanges": true
}
```

Both can be accessed anywhere in Cypress tests:

```
Cypress.env('someDummyEnvironemntVar')   => "fooBar"
Cypress.config('backendBaseURL')   => "http://localhost:8080/api/v2"
```

Comment: That's the same as my second part section. If I want to call `someDummyEnvironemntVar`, I'm now have to do like this: `${Cypress.config('backendBaseURL')}/${Cypress.env('someDummyEnvironemntVar')}`

Answer (score 0):

We have a separate file called settings.js (cypress/settings.js). Which holds the configuration for the API:

```js
export const apiUri = 'APIURL'
export const apiOauthSecret = 'TOKEN'
```

To actually use the variable apiUri we import it in the file where we want to use it:

```js
import {apiUri, apiOauthSecret} from '../settings'

Cypress.Commands.add('apiRequest', (endPoint, options) => {
  const token = options.token || JSON.parse(window.sessionStorage.getItem('oauth-token') || '{}').accessToken
  if (token) {
    return cy.request({
      failOnStatusCode: false,
      ...requestOptions({
        ...options,
        token
      }),
      url: `${apiUri}/${endPoint}`
    })
  }
  return cy
})
```

This results in being able to use apiUri and baseUrl next to eachother

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't thought about the custom commands, looks good actually!
One thing tho, did this mean you have separated commands for each of network commands like `cy.request` `cy.route` etc. ?

Comment: No, I use visit() for going to the base URL, route() for mocking API-calls, request() is not used.

But for a normal environment without any stubbing I only use custom commands to build API-request (for example create a complete person).

Comment: hmm, I didn't quite follow here. So, basically I have to make a custom command for `cy.route()` to make it prepend the endpoint URL with my `apiBaseUrl` ?